# Windows 8 installation fails to start

Tags: windows-8, boot, bios

I'm trying to fresh install Windows 8 Pro x64 bit to a blank SSD, but am having trouble getting the Windows 8 installer to even start.

What happens...

1. I place the Windows 8 DVD in the drive, start the computer, press a key to boot from DVD.
2. Windows 8 logo appears, and hangs for a couple of minutes.
3. A spinning progress indicator appears, the screen goes black (like its transitioning to the next step), and remains black. There is no cursor prompt or anything... just a black screen.
4. Eventually after letting it sit for 5 mins, the computer flashes a bright blue screen with white text for an instant (similar to a BSOD), then the computer reboots.
5. Cycle repeats.

Right now I suspect two things: 1) secure boot settings, and 2) graphics card drivers.

**Secure boot**:

- I'm using a [ASUS Crosshair V Formula](http://www.asus.com/Motherboards/CROSSHAIR_V_FORMULA) motherboard with the latest BIOS ROM (v1703, 10/17/12)
- In the BIOS settings, it's set to use UEFI for the DVD drive boot device (for when it loads the installer from DVD.)
- There is no explicit UEFI or secure boot option for the SSD boot device.
- This begs the question... does this motherboard support Windows 8? The product website seems to suggest so, since you can download Windows 8 support files for it.
- If it does, what settings would I have to change to ensure its using secure boot for Windows 8?

**Graphics card**:

- I'm using 2x RAEDON HD 5870 cards (linked with Crossfire)
- If this is the problem, I'd have no idea how to fix it...

Ideas?

**EDIT:**
I think I can rule out the video cards, since I was able to run the Windows 7 installer with the same hardware, no problem. I find it highly unlikely that Win7 setup can handle my video cards, but Win8 setup cannot.

Comment: Only a guess, but remove 1 Radeon HD and looks if this fixes it.

Answer (score 0):

If the computer is unable to boot from Windows 8 DVD with the Secure Boot option turned on, the boot screen should print out a message that says it's not a bootable device. Try this method and it may help you out:

Enter into the computer's BIOS. Find an option called "SATA Mode", change it from IDE or Compatible mode to AHCI Mode.

Comment: Good call, however, my BIOS was already set to AHCI when setup failed to load. On a similar and interesting point, when I tried to install Windows 7 on the same exact hardware (and settings), its setup *also* hung on 'Setup is starting', until I switched from AHCI to IDE mode, after which the Windows 7 install completed successfully. I have not tried Windows 8 install with IDE mode yet, and my BIOS does not have a 'Compatible' option to use.

Comment: IDE mode is also shown as Compatible mode in some BIOS versions. I've purchased a Dell computer comes with Windows 8 pre-installed, it runs normally with AHCI mode, but it will always fail to boot if I change it to Compatible mode. That is why I recommend you give a try with the hard drive mode. Maybe IDE mode would work on your situation.

Answer (score -2):

I have found post on a forum which might give you the answer. Did you see [this](http://forums.hexus.net/help-quick-relief-tech-headaches/275869-uefi-windows-8-secure-boot.html#post2819505)?

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't really tell me anything about how to fix my issue.

Comment: Link only answers are discouraged, please include a summary of what was in the link, in case it ever goes dead.